# How to propagate windows environment variable for powershell run from cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, cygwin

I have installed cygwin and I am about to execute a script written in powershell. I do it like this:

```
powershell "& ""C:\my\script.ps1"""
```

This works as expected, I have to do this that way because in that script I am executing another external command and so on ...

I would like to add some environment variable to that script, so I would like to write something like

```
powershell "$FOO="bar"; & ""C:\my\script.ps1"""
```

so I can then access `$FOO` variable in the script and do something with it. The idea is that if that variable is not defined, I use some default value. I know that this could be also achieved with some environment variables or I could put these variables to the profile (profile.ps1) but I want to get rid of that file so I need none and I can override the default value with the variables as I showed.

but is says that:

```
=bar : The term '=bar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
```

So I was thinking that something like this could work:

```
powershell { $web = "google.com" ; & ping.exe $web }
```

But it works only in powershell console and not in cygwin, it cygwin it says that

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

So it seems like that `&` is treaten as bash character. I tried to escape it in thousand ways, e.g.

```
bash -c "'powershell { \$web = \"google.com\" ; & ping.exe \$web }'"
```

But this is the output

```
bash: powershell { $web = "google.com" ; & ping.exe $web }: command not found
```

Thank you for a hint.

**UPDATE**

I am able to do this:

```
 powershell "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {\$env:FOO = \"google.com\" ; & ""C:\my\script.ps1"" }"
```

But when I am trying to access that `FOO` variable throught `$env:FOO` it is empty, it seems like I am unable to do so because that script is running in another scope or what ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this command will pass an environment variable from cygwin (`$FOO="bar"`) to powershell, then run another powershell command (`dir env:`) which lists the environment variables (proving that it was set):

```
powershell "\$env:FOO=\"bar\";dir env:"
```

replace the `dir env:` part with your script call and this should work for you.

edit: here's the command (quoted slightly differently) including the call to an external script:

```
powershell '$env:FOO="bar";& "C:\script name.ps1"'
```